# Custom money TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I just started learning Flutter and i am trying to figure out how the user can enter an amount in a TextField ,for example 1234567 , should look like this when user is typing :

```
1.00
12.00
123.00
1 234.00
12 345.00
123 456.00
1 234 567.00
```

I tried using this library : mask_text_input_formatter, but i can't figure out how to do it. Here is my code

```
 var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(
      mask: '### ### ###.00', filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')});

TextFormField(
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
onChanged: (value) {},
decoration: InputDecoration(
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
 hintText: 'Amount',
 border: OutlineInputBorder(),
 ),
   validator: (value) {
   if (value.isEmpty) {
return 'Please enter some text';
}
return null;
},
),
```

Any idea on how to achieve that result.

Comment: In the 4th example why would you want a space after 3 digits? `123 4.00` Would you rather want it to be `1 234.00`?

Comment: @SunitGautam oh yes my mistake. i edited my question

Comment: What's the problem you are facing with your code? An error or unexpected output?

Comment: You can use a controller and in the on Changed property of textfield append ". 00' to the controller.text... Never tried it but it seems it will work..

Comment: @SunitGautam when i type it doesn't add the last two zeros (',00').

Comment: @Abbas can you elaborate more please

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize a text controller and assign it to the text field. Update its value on change in input!

```
TextEditingController _moneyController = TextEditingController();
@override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  _moneyController.text = '.00';
}

TextFormField(
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
onChanged: (value) {},
decoration: InputDecoration(
prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
 hintText: 'Amount',
 border: OutlineInputBorder(),
 ),
   validator: (value) {
   if (value.isEmpty) {
return 'Please enter some text';
}
return null;
},
//added code here
controller: _moneyController,
),
```

Comment: I tried the code and it doesn't work as expected! I'll see if I can make any change

Comment: I'm precisely not sure what you want exactly but I have edited my answer to suit something.. let me know if that is what you wanted!

Comment: this code just initialise the textfield with ',00' . what i want is while the user is typing the amount i want this ',00' to always be next to what he is typing